# 1 to 1..0 in Django / MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, innodb, django-orm

I'd like to get some advice on how to handle 1 to 1..0 relationships in Django.

I have a list of products which have many attributes which are null much of the time (for up to 95% of products). Rather than keep them in the products table, I've put them in separate tables, so I have the following (with age and weight as the sparse attributes):

```
products
    id
    colour
    height
    width

product_age
    id
    product_id (FK)
    age

product_weight
    id
    product_id (FK)
    weight
```

etc

Firstly, I know that in InnoDB, nulls don't take up any space, so I'm thinking that maybe it wouldn't affect performance if I moved the sparse attributes to the products table

Secondly, if I do keep all of these 1 to 1..0 relationships, how do I handle this in models.py. I currently have:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class ProductAge(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class ProductWeight(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=13)
```

It's unwieldy to have all of these as different objects, meaning that I would have to remember which attributes are separate objects when coding.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

### UPDATE

Inheritance works here but it still seems a bit messy. I would need something like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class ProductWithAge(Product):
    age = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class ProductWithAgeAndWeight(Product):
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=13)
```

I'd then only actually use ProductWithAgeAndWeight in my code, as I could access all give fields from within this. The database would split the data between three tables. Maybe my naming is the issue... any thoughts?

Comment: Inheritance may be a solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267428/how-to-inherit-objects-in-django  ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501822/coding-an-inventory-system-with-polymorphic-items-and-manageable-item-types

Comment: I don't recommend that you implement a schemaless model. I did that a long time ago and it turned out pretty bad as I had to define the fields in the Form anyway, the schemaless hacks became a useless bloat layer I finally had to get rid of. Early optimization is the root of all evil. Keep it simple, keep it stupid. just my 2 cent.

Comment: I agree with @jpic. Design your models in a way that makes sense, don't worry about optimization unless you notice problems. Many times, when trying to over-optimize you actually make things worse. Do what makes the most sense, and then test and optimize as needed from there.

Comment: I may have phrased my question poorly... I'm not considering a schema-less model. (I edited the question to clarify). I'm considering a normalised approach with a table for products plus a table for each of weight and age.

danihp's suggestion of inheritance could work but it's not as clean as the linked example, because it's random which entries have a weight or age rather than it being a particular type of product

I'll play around with normalisation and post back

Comment: Added an update on inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need separate Primary keys in the 2 extra tables. The `product_id` is enough:

```
products
    id
    colour
    height
    width

product_age
    product_id (PK) (FK)
    age

product_weight
    product_id (PK) (FK)
    weight
```

The model would be:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class ProductAge(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    product_id.primary_key=True 
    age = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class ProductWeight(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    product_id.primary_key=True 
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=13)
```

---

If you want to avoid the complexity of inserting/updating the products, you should work with the one `products` table that allows Nulls in the 2 rows. Nulls do take space but it's not that big that you should care.

Comment: ended up keeping in main table

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield).

```
class ProductAge(models.Model):
    age = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class ProductWeight(models.Model):
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class Product(models.Model):
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    age = models.OneToOneField(ProductAge, null=True, blank=True)
    weight = models.OneToOneField(ProductWeight, null=True, blank=True)
```

This way you can directly access `.age` and `.weight` attributes directly from `product` instance.

The way you've set it up with foreign keys, you'd have get list via `.age_set` and  `.weight_set`, check if the list is not empty, then take first element. Tedious and error prone. And the inheritance is just not the way to go at all.

Comment: The problem with this is that you've still got lots of nulls in the product table for age_id and weight_id... I might as well just put the age and weight field themselves back in if I'm okay with the nulls, no?

Comment: Basically yes, unless you're having BLOBs or more fields, there is no real reason to split it into separate models. Also, keep in mind that what's proper Django ORM way, might not be the optimal RDBMs way.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are going for is best accomplished with model managers,
and one table for products, or 2 tables, one table "Product" and another table "ProductAttribute" that stores things like {'attribute_name':'age','attribute_value':13,'product_id':3'} with a ProductAttributeManager

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/

Comment: Can you explain how you would use managers with just one table? thx

Comment: Er, on second thought (edit) you kind of need at least 2 tables to efficiently track all of the data.  A manager on just one table would be kind of silly.  A manager would make sense to basically take generic 'attribute' name/value pairs, and add accessor methods to the product class specific to age / weight.  Managers simply give you more freedom with how data is fetched for a given model class.